# Drawing marbles from a bag

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Lucy is playing a game. She starts with one blue marble in her bowl and five marbles (two red, three blue) in her bag. She then begins drawing marbles from the bag. If she draws a blue marble, she adds it to the bowl; if a red one is drawn, then she returns it, as well as one blue marble from the bowl, to the bag. The game ends if all the blue marbles end up in the bag or in the bowl. What is the probability that the latter occurs?

We know that the first marble Lucy draws is a blue one or else there would be no blues left in the bowl. I have attempted this question many different ways by looking at the three cases of her draws: BR...; BBR...; BBB. I am not sure if this is the right way to look at it and if I should be looking at it more algebraically by getting an equation for our desired probability, $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: For $k=1,2,3$ let $p_k$ be the probability that the blue marbles end up in the bowl if she starts with two red and $k$ blue marbles in the bag and $4-k$ marbles in the bowl; we want $p_3$.

Start with $p_1$: she has $1$ blue and $2$ red marbles in the bag, so with probability $\frac13$ she draws the blue marble, and the game ends with all $4$ marbles in the bowl. With probability $\frac23$ she draws a red marble, and in effect the game starts over with $k=2$. Thus,

$$p_1=\frac13+\frac23p_2\;.$$

Now consider $p_2$. With probability $\frac12$ she draws a blue marble, and in effect the game starts over with $k=1$; and with probability $\frac12$ she draws a red marble, and in effect the game starts over with $k=3$. Thus,

$$p_2=\frac12p_1+\frac12p_3=\frac16+\frac13p_2+\frac12p_3\;,$$

and we can solve for $p_2$ to get

$$p_2=\frac14+\frac34p_3\;.$$

Now see if you can finish it by working out $p_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_n$ be the probability of ending with all blue marbles in the bowl if you start with $n$ blue marbles in the bowl.  You want $p_1$.  Now from the rules of the game it is clear that
$$p_0=0\ ,\quad p_4=1\ ,$$
and if $n=1,2,3$ we have
$$p_n=P(\hbox{draw red})p_{n-1}+P(\hbox{draw blue})p_{n+1}
  =\frac{2}{6-n}p_{n-1}+\frac{4-n}{6-n}p_{n+1}\ .$$
From this you can calculate $p_1=\frac{3}{11}$.

Comment: This is slightly confusing. How does $P(\hbox{draw red})p_{n-1}+P(\hbox{draw blue})p_{n+1}$? Also, wouldn't that sort of violate the problem because you are seeming to say that we can draw 5 blue marbles for example then draw a red and that is the same probability of ending with 4 blue marbles?

Comment: Please read more carefully!!!  My equation is stated for $n=1,2,3$, so there is no possibility that $n+1=5$.

Comment: My question is how do you know that equation is true that you wrote.

Comment: If you have $n$ blue marbles in the bowl ($n=1,2,3$) then there are two possibilities: draw a red from the bag, then the number of blues in the bowl becomes $n-1$; or draw a blue from the bag, then the number in the bowl becomes $n+1$.

Comment: But this drawing $1$ red doesn't work for $n = 1$.

Comment: Why not? $\,\!$

Comment: Because then you would have 0 blues in the bowl and we don't want that, right?

Comment: It's not a question of what we want, it's a question of the rules of the game.  The rules in your question say that you **can** have $0$ blues in the bowl, and then the game ends.  That means no further moves are made, so it is impossible to get all the blues in the bowl and the probability of doing so is zero.  See my first equation: $p_0=0$.